# Como mostrar ad ao fechar meu aplicativo

Tags: android

Quero mostrar meu ad quando o usuário aperta para "voltar" onde devo lançar esse código: AdBuddiz.showAd(activity);

Comment: Qual biblioteca de `Ads` esta usando`? `AdMob`?

Comment: Estou usando o AdBuddiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para alcançar a solução você deve sobreescrever o método `onBackPressed` da `Activity`.

Uma solução seria:

```
public class SuaActivity extends Activity {

    // Demais codigo de sua Activity...

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Usuario apertou o botão voltar.
        // Essa chamada é opcional, mas é uma boa prática
        // deixar o comportamento padrão ocorrer
        super.onBackPressed();

        // Mostra seu Ads
        AdBuddiz.showAd(this);
    }
}
```

No caso do `AdBuddiz`, você precisa registrar um `AdBuddizDelegate` para escutar por eventos que ocorrem com o `Ads`.

Para complementar o comportamento desejado, iremos usar alguns eventos para continuar o processo de "voltar". Iremos usar o evento de `didFailToShowAd`, `didClick` e `didHideAd` para voltar efetivamente<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>**Estou supondo que ainda não usa o `AdBuddizDelegate`, e que somente a `SuaActivity` chama o `Ads`. Caso contrário é preciso adaptar o código para tratar multiplos usos, já que o `AdBuddiz` só permite 1 AdBuddizDelegate em todo seu app**

Aplicando em sua `Activity` ficaria:

```
public class SuaActivity extends Activity implements AdBuddizDelegate {

    // Flag para indicar se o usuário pode voltar (o Ads ja foi exibido ou falhou).
    boolean mAdShownOrFailed = false;

    // Flag para indicar que o usuário ja apertou o botao de voltar
    boolean mBackPressed = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Restante codigo do seu onCreate

        // Registramos o AdBuddizDelegate.
        AdBuddiz.setDelegate(this);
    }

    // Restante do codigo de sua Activity...

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Usuario apertou o botão voltar.
        // A chamada ao super.onBackPressed() é opcional, mas é uma boa prática
        // deixar o comportamento padrão ocorrer

        // Como o Ads ja foi mostrado ou nao pode ser carregado,
        // podemos permitir o usuario voltar
        if(mAdShownOrFailed) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        mBackPressed = true;

        // Mostra seu Ads
        AdBuddiz.showAd(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void didCacheAd() {
        // Ad foi colocado no cache, nao precisamos fazer nada
    }

    @Override
    public void didShowAd() {
        // O Ads foi mostrado, podemos permitir que ele aperte o
        // botao de voltar novamente para sair.
        mAdShownOrFailed = mBackPressed && true;
    }

    @Override
    public void didFailToShowAd(AdBuddizError error) {
        // O Ads falhou ao carregar, o usuario pode sair assim mesmo
        mAdShownOrFailed = mBackPressed && true;
        // Voce pode fechar a Activity caso queira, chamando onBackPressed()
        //onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void didClick() {
        // Usuario clicou, podemos fechar a Activity
        mAdShownOrFailed = mBackPressed && true;
        onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void didHideAd() {
        // Usuario fechou o Ads, podemos fechar a Activity
        mAdShownOrFailed = mBackPressed && true;
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostra o ads ao "voltar" mas continua com app aberto(politica do google), so depois que o ads for fechado que o app some.

Comment: Ok, vou atualizar, só um minuto para eu ver a documentação.